# Extract business logic from asp.net core api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have developed a simple asp.net core API project that sends an email giving a recipient, a template name and a list of tags, used to valorize template variables.
Basically, this project exposes a POST API that accepts a JSON object with the required information to send the email.

I want to get rid of the overhead of HTTP communication and extract the send email logic to a kind of class library project that I can use in all the projects where I need to send emails.

In the email project I use `Services` and `Dipendency Injection`; to provide an example with the class that valorize email template and send email is a service, and this is its constructor:

```
public EmailService(IOptions<SmtpSettings> smtpSettings, DataContext dbContext, ILogger<EmailService> logger)
{
    ....
}
```

that uses DI to obtain:

- **smtpSettings**: object that contains settings from `appsettings.json`
- **dbContext**: `entity framework` database context, used to store sent emails (debugging purpose)
- **logger**: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` object, used to log informations, also on files using `NLog` provider.

Then i register the service as a scoped service in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
```

And i use the service in API controller with DI:

```
public SendEmailController(ILogger<SendEmailController> logger, IEmailService emailService)
{
    ....
}
```

I need to save all this logic and move it to a new project, that then I can use in all the asp.net projects where I need an email service.

I can't just move the `EmailService` class to a library project because I lose all service functionality (i use the email service with DI in API controllers) and all DI features of the service itself.

I'm struggling with how can I reuse the email service (and other related services) in other projects, without exposing an HTTP REST API to let other projects use the email service (most of the time I use 1 instance of email service with only 1 API consumer).

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly, but you can easily copy the EmailService to a different Project and still use DI to use it in your controller. You just have to register the EmailService in your Startup.

Comment: @ChristophK Yes but email service itself needs other services with DI and if i move it to an other project those DI are not resolved.

Comment: @soriolicomputec then you have to manage those coupling too. Either make the dependent libraries using DI or something else. In your case it seems you need to register your EmailService dependencies in the DI container and spin them up, and possibly resolve them via constructor.

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi can you please provide a basic example of this implementation?

Comment: I can help you if you can share your code.